# Saving extracted content from VBA in powerpoint as a new excel file

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I'm new to coding, VBA and VBA in powerpoint, so this might be basic but I cant seem to get around it. I'm trying to extract some text from powerpoint files and store it separately in a new file. I found a code online that helps me output the required text onto a notepad file. However, I need it as an excel file. Every search online leads me to excel based VBA but I need to export from Powerpoint to Excel (and maybe do so basic formatting in it, like converting text to numbers or making a column bold). Following is the relevant/ exporting portion of my whole code. Please take a look and help thanks.

PS: I plan to compile the code as an Add-in for a few people with limited technical expertise, so If possible, I'd request a simple/straightforward solution or something that will work on any PC or version of powerpoint/excel. I've read making your code reference-dependant may require whoever runs the code to make references,etc before they are successfully able to run it.

```
Dim strFilename As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer
Dim PathSep As String
```

....Code that does the extraction from the Active Presentation....

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
intFileNum = FreeFile

' PC-Centricity Alert!
' This assumes that the file has a .PPT extension and strips it off to make the text file name.
strFilename = ActivePresentation.Path _
    & PathSep _
    & Mid$(ActivePresentation.Name, 1, Len(ActivePresentation.Name) - 4) _
    & "_Titles.TXT"

Open strFilename For Output As intFileNum
Print #intFileNum, strTitles

NormalExit:
Close intFileNum
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume NormalExit

End Sub
```

Comment: There's code to extract a presentation's text to CSV or Excel on the same PPTFAQ.com site where you found the (partially quoted) code above.  Search for:  Export the text of a presentation to a CSV/Excel file

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks Steve!!

Comment: Just from looking at that snippet, I wouldn't really recommend packaging that as an add-in for anyone unless you want to responsible for debugging it when they have problems.  The very first thing I see happening is someone running it with a .pptx extension and then you are getting called over to fix it.  If you post the whole funcitoning code over on CodeReview you might get some input on how to better prepare it for distribution.

Comment: CBRF23 makes a good point. The code snipped was written long before MS Office went to 4-char extensions.  This might be a better choice:  ActivePresentation.Path _
    & "\" _
    & Mid$(ActivePresentation.Name, 1, InStr(ActivePresentation.Name, ".") - 1) _
    & "_Titles.TXT"